# Remove branding and title link from embeded youtube video

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube.net-api

Can anyone please suggest a way to remove link back to youtube and branding (watermark or logo) from embedded youtube video.

The below tag remove branding:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8pjJ-Czqpps?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0" width="420"></iframe>
```

The below tag remove title link:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed  /8pjJ-Czqpps?showinfo=0" width="420"></iframe>
```

But cant able to make all together happening.

Please help.

Comment: if you don't want youtube branding *or* links... maybe host the video yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, YouTube says:

```
If you use the Embed-able Player on your website, you may not modify, build upon, or block     
any portion or functionality of the Embed-able Player, including but not limited to links    
back to the YouTube website.
```

So, don't try to use CSS tricks especially when you are an Adsense publisher.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to hide the title by providing a **div** (by applying css **position:absolute**) above **iframe**.

I have removed the YouTube logo by providing **modestbranding=1**.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:black;height:30px;width:420px;position:absolute">
</div>
<div>
<iframe id="div1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8pjJ-Czqpps?modestbranding=1&rel=0&fs=0"
        width="420">
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best answer for your question.

```
<iframe width=”213″ height=”120″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/nhP1d-NjFHQ?rel=0″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The highlighted section is what we will be adding to. All it takes is adding &showinfo=0 to the ened of the YouTube URL before the closing bracket. Note that “rel=0″ refers to showing related videos once your video has ended, so if it’s not there simply put your code snippet after a ‘?’ like you see preceding ‘rel=0′ Once you set showinfo to equal zero, you should get a nice, clean YouTube video right on your website. You’re embed code will then look like this:

```
<iframe width=”213″ height=”120″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/nhP1d-NjFHQ?rel=0&showinfo=0″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The original article you found [here](https://www.killerspots.com/remove-youtube-title-when-embedding-videos/).

Comment: This does not remove the logo.

Comment: You can add ?modestbranding=1 to your url. That will remove the logo.

Comment: Yes, but they're mutually exclusive. You can't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
youryoutubelink/.../?rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;showinfo=0"
```

This removes Logo and Title at the same time. `Modestbranding` doesn't work at the same time as `showinfo`, it's either one or the other, hence the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't get rid of both as it's against the [Terms of Service](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the way to remove everything but the initial watermark/play button.
If you use the div trick coupled with the the modestbranding=1 and the controls=0, you get a clean youtube video with no titles or links whatsoever.

This is what I did:

```
<div style="background-color:black;height:30px;width:420px;position:absolute">
&nbsp;</div>
<div>
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" id="div1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;controls=0" width="420"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append &modestbranding=1 to the end of your URL or after another parameter and the link will no longer appear.

source:http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/779427-youtube-embed-tricks-other-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube iFrame API has a ['Getting Started' code snippet](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) but fails to mention how you pass the parameters.

### API

You need to pass all your parameters in a 'playerVars' object like a so

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          playerVars: {
                theme: 'dark',
                wmode: 'opaque',
                autohide: '1',
                autoplay: '0',
                controls: '1',
                modestbranding: '0',
                disablekb: '0',
                showinfo: '0',
                rel: '0'
          },
          videoId: '123123123123',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
```

### iFrame Embed

The alternative is using the iframe embed and pass your arguments in the query string like a so

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/123123123?wmode=opaque&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&disablekb=1&controls=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://bdtune24.com/gtv-live/
You can use this Plugin if your site build in wordpress.[https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/]

After install That....you can embed any youtube or vimeo video....
Like this: `[videojs youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iiCkqA533E"]`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8pjJ-Czqpps?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&nologo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```